# how do i select an interpreter on my IDE which is Python IDLE

Tags: python, tensorflow, python-idle

How do I select an interpreter on my IDE which is Python IDLE? I can't find the options to do that.

I managed to install Tensorflow but it only works when I import it in the terminal, not in my current IDE

What I want: Make my current IDE use the Python.exe that has been provided when I installed Tensorflow on my computer

What I tried: Using PYCHARM, it works (like a charm!) but I can't do that stuff like import module then have " >>> " then issue my commands etc...

Comment: Did you try `import subprocess` and then run `subprocess.Popen(['/path/to/your/tensorflow_executable'])` ?

Comment: Or if you'd like to run tensorflow commands from within a python script just execute `pip install tensorflow` in your regular command line interface, then start Python IDLE and just type `import tensorflow` and write the rest of your script.

Comment: I can't understand the question.  I hope @SB87 did.  If not, try re-wording.

Comment: I'll try the second solution @SB87, but if I write that amn't I ( sry broken english ) going to install tensorflow twice?

Answer (score 0):

IDLE does NOT provide such functionality - it works through idlelib, a package from stdlib so it's executed using `pythonw -m idlelib`. To change interprenter in IDLE, call it using a different interprenter - `"C:\path\to\your\python\interprenter\pythonw.exe" -m idlelib` (make sure idlelib is installed for target interprenter).