# How do I install and import modules such as numpy and pandas? I want to use the IDLE editing/run environment, and I have Python 3.10 installed

Tags: python, numpy

How do I install and import modules such as numpy and pandas?  I want to use the IDLE editing/run environment, and I have Python 3.10 installed.

The error I get when I run from the IDLE Shell 3.10.0 is shown below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Family/Desktop/UD_work/distillation.py", line 7, in <module>
    import numpy as np
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'
```

I don't get the error when I run from the anaconda prompt

In your answer, please do not assume that I know how to do any of the administrative stuff.  For example, in reading through answers of similar questions, there was a suggestion to issue the 'which python' command to find out whether more than one version is installed and which one is called by IDLE.  I have no idea where to type that command.

Comment: simply `pip install numpy` and `pip install pandas`

Comment: It seems like you're executing IDLE from a different Interpreter, than your anaconda environment. To execute IDLE from your preferred Interpreter (should be anaconda in your case): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43167500/how-do-i-select-an-interpreter-on-my-ide-which-is-python-idle

Comment: Thanks Yannick.  pythow.exe -m idlelib  did the trick.  I had to navigate to the directory where my python executable is installed, but otherwise it worked fine.  P.S.  I issued this command from the 'anaconda prompt'.  When I did, a new shell was spawned.  I opened my python code from within that shell and then just selected the run command.          Will I have to issue that command to get that shell open every time I want to work on my python code?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same versions of IDLE and Python installed on my Windows PC. When I attempt to run "pip install" from the command line (CLI), I get a syntax error.

- First, open the Windows command prompt.
- Type the Windows key and "r" on your keyboard.
- Type "control panel" and press Enter or click OK.
- Click on System and Security.
- Click on Windows Tools.

You'll find the command prompt icon here. Double-click the command prompt icon. DO NOT run python (pythonw.exe or py) from the command line of the command prompt (CLI) to download your module. Type the following at the command line. Your command line should look similar to this:

C:\Users\your user_name> pip install Numpy

Do the same for whatever other module you want to download.